# How to use gallery on apps that only allow to get a picture from a camera app?

Tags: debugging, android-camera, android-camera2, apktool

Is there a way to upload images through gallery on apps that only allows the images to be taken by camera?
I know there are apps like fakecamera which allows the same but a recent update to the app in which I upload images through gallery using FakeCamera has disabled this functionality. Every time I click on camera button in the app only my mobile camera is opened (earlier whenever I clicked the camera button, a selection dialog used to came to select between fake camera or camera to upload image). But now only my default camera is opened every time. If this needs to Mod the apk, I am ready to do that but please someone help me out with this, I am so frustrated.....

Comment: If your app launches the camera app via an intent and specifies the camera class for this intent, you may need to patch (and rebuild) the app to work around this restriction.

Comment: Can you please tell a way to patch the already compiled app using android studio.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with Android Studio. Usually you disassemble the APK with **apktool**, change its code (in smali) and/or resources, and reassemble in back with same **apktool**. Your mileage may differ, the level of app defense against hackers largely varies.

Comment: can someone here do this for me please, i am a complete newbie to this coding world.